# Cannot convert value of type '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I'm trying to get to the `url` of `thumbnail_images` from the JSON response I got as shown in this picture below:
[image]
So in order to reach to the `url` I made a class called `Posts` in which

```
class Posts: NSObject {

    var title: String?
    var excerpt: String?
    var content: String?
    var thumbnail_images: [ThumbImages] = []

    init(dict: [String: AnyObject])
    {
        super.init()

        self.title = dict["title"] as? String
        self.excerpt = dict["excerpt"] as? String
        self.content = dict["content"] as? String

        if let postImage = dict["thumbnail_images"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

            for img in postImage  {
                self.thumbnail_images.append(ThumbImages(dict: img))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line `self.thumbnail_images.append(ThumbImages(dict: img))` I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'

That is it for my questions but I think it's relevant to share more code as in order to reach to `url` I had to make to more classes `ThumbImages` and `MedLargeImage`. Which has the following code:

```
class ThumbImages: NSObject {

    var medium_large: [MedLargeImage] = []

    init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {

        super.init()

        if let imgURL = dict["medium_large"] {

            for iURL in imgURL as! [AnyObject] {
                medium_large.append(MedLargeImage(dict: iURL as! [String : AnyObject]))
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the screenshot. So finally I'm in the room where I can get the URL:

```
class MedLargeImage: NSObject {

    var imageUrl: String?

    init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {

        super.init()
        self.imageUrl = dict["url"] as? String

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If I change `if let postImage` in Posts class to:

```
if let postImage = dict["thumbnail_images"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

            for img in postImage  {
                self.thumbnail_images.append(ThumbImages(dict: img))
            }
        }
```

The error is gone but for the if condition never gets true.

Comment: You treat `postImage` as an array but it's a dictionary. That's why you get this tuple when looping, you get tuples of keys and values from the dictionary.

Comment: @Moritz If I change it to `if let postImage = dict["thumbnail_images"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]` it works but `if let` doesn't move to run `for` command.

Comment: Don't use `[String:AnyObject]` as JSON dictionary representation in Swift 3 at all. A JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` because all JSON dictionary values are (Swift) value types. Moreover, looking at your current implementation for `Posts`, I see no reason to inherit from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- First of all classes are supposed to be named in singular form `Post` / `ThumbImage`. The datasource array e.g. `posts` contains `Post` instances and each `Post` instance contains an array `thumbnailImages` of  `ThumbImage` instances. These semantics make it easier to understand the design.
- Second of all JSON dictionaries in Swift 3+ are `[String:Any]`
- Third of all according to the initialization rules the `super` call must be performed **after** initializing all stored properties.

The value of key `thumbnail_images` is a dictionary containing dictionaries. The error occurs because you are using the **array** enumeration syntax which treats the dictionary as an array of tuples.

The dictionary can be parsed to use the `key` as size name and the `value` to pass the parameters.

I have no idea why you are using `NSObject` subclasses but I'm sure you have your reasons.

---

This is the `Thumbnail` class

```
class ThumbImage: NSObject {

    let size: String
    var url : URL?
    let width : Int
    let height : Int

    init(size : String, parameters: [String: Any]) {

        self.size = size
        if let urlString = parameters["url"] as? String {
            self.url = URL(string: urlString)
        }
        self.width = parameters["width"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.height = parameters["height"] as? Int ?? 0
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and this the `Post` class

```
class Post: NSObject {

    var title: String
    var excerpt: String
    var content: String
    var thumbnailImages = [ThumbImage]()

    init(dict: [String: Any])
    {
        self.title = dict["title"] as? String ?? ""
        self.excerpt = dict["excerpt"] as? String ?? ""
        self.content = dict["content"] as? String ?? ""
        super.init()
        if let images = dict["thumbnail_images"] as? [String: [String:Any] ]  {
            for (key, value) in images {
                thumbnailImages.append(ThumbImage(size: key, parameters: value))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that error message because you are looping over `postImage` as if it's an array, when it's actually a dictionary. In your `ThumbImages` class initialiser, you are expecting to take in a dictionary. However, since you are looping through the `postImage` dictionary, this returns you tuples in key value pairs instead.

Hence when you try to pass in this tuple into the `ThumbImages` initialiser, the compiler complains that it is unable to convert your tuple into a dictionary.

Passing in the dictionary immediately will resolve the error:

```
if let postImage = dict["thumbnail_images"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    self.thumbnail_images.append(ThumbImages(dict: postImage))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass tuple as dictionary directly.
instead use this:
 let dicFromArray = [tuple.key :tuple.value]